# Why can't I connect to AWS using awscli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How should I debug this?

Trying:

```
aws --debug ec2 describe-instances
```

Gives:

> 2014-11-07 10:27:49,394 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG -
>   Sending http request:  2014-11-07 10:27:49,395
>   - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO -
>   Starting new HTTPS connection (1): ec2.us-east-1c.amazonaws.com

And then:

> Timeout: (, 'Connection to ec2.us-east-1c.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)')

Trying:

> nc -vz ec2.us-east-1c.amazonaws.com 443

Gives:

> DNS fwd/rev mismatch: ec2.us-east-1c.amazonaws.com !=

And then:

> unallocated.barefruit.co.uk ec2.us-east-1c.amazonaws.com
>   [92.242.140.21] 443 (https) : Connection timed out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong: **`ec2.us-east-1c.amazonaws.com`**

It should be: **`ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`**

You need to provide `REGION` Endpoint to AWS CLI. What you are providing looks like is Availability zone endpoint (??).

Show us how are you passing the `REGION` parameter to AWS CLI ?

Comment: That was it. I set it up in aws config. I got it from the ec2instances. Didn't realize they were showing the availability zone. Thanks.

Comment: awesome; this has helped me even after 2 years since answer appeared

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you are behind a corp. proxy/firewall that is configured to intercept SSL connections as well as regular HTTP connections on port 80.

Because the command line tools aren't configured to trust the proxy cert, you're getting an error.

Comment: Just behind a home router. There is no proxy. I can connect to ports 80 and 443 outbound just fine in general.